# How to fix load error when launching Ruby on Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am getting an error often. For example, when running the SQLite3 server:

```
$ rails s
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/exe/rails (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I tried all the different suggestions I have found here like `bundle install rails`. I am running Ruby v. 2.6.5 but in the error above it mentions 2.6.0.

```
$ which -a ruby
/c/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby
/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby
```

Ruby version:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x64-mingw32]
```

gem file:

```
`source 'https://rubygems.org'
    git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

    ruby '2.6.5'

    gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
    gem 'simple_form'
    gem 'will_paginate'
    gem 'news-api'
    gem 'httparty'
    gem 'executables'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
  gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
  gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

`bin/rails s` command:

```
$ bin/rails s
bin/rails:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands (LoadError)
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

gem env command

```
    $ gem env
    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.5 (2019-10-01 patchlevel 114) [x64-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/darre/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin/git.EXE
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby26-x64/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/darre/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x64-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - C:/Users/darre/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\Users\darre\.rbenv\bin
     - C:\Users\darre\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
     - C:\Users\darre\bin
     - C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
     - C:\Windows\system32
     - C:\Windows
     - C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
     - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
     - C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
     - C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
     - C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
     - C:\WINDOWS\system32
     - C:\WINDOWS
     - C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
     - C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
     - C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH
     - C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
     - C:\Users\darre\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
     - C:\Users\darre\AppData\Local\atom\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin
     - C:\Python27
     - C:\adb
     - C:\Program Files\nodejs
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin
     - C:\Users\darre\scoop\apps\yarn\current\Yarn\bin
     - C:\Users\darre\scoop\persist\yarn\global\node_modules\.bin
     - C:\Users\darre\scoop\shims
     - C:\Ruby26-x64\bin
     - C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd
     - C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\bin
     - C:\Users\darre\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
     - C:\Users\darre\AppData\Local\atom\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin
     - C:\Python27
     - C:\Users\darre\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
     - C:\Users\darre\AppData\Roaming\npm
     - C:\Users\darre\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
     - C:\Program Files\heroku\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
```

Comment: `gem info` might help. Copy the output and paste it into your question, formatting it appropriately, without using "edit" or "update" tags as we can tell what changed and when.

Comment: please show your Gemfile and check if there's any file indicating ruby version like `.ruby-version`. and the fastest solution might be run `bin/rails s` under the project root path

Comment: @theTinMan i have about 89 installed gems do you want to see output from gem info command on all of these?

Comment: @Darren what Rails version do you have at the moment? Try running `C:\> rails -v`. If none is found then you should install it: `C:\> gem install rails`

Comment: @achalar i can't even use the rails -v command without throwing this error  $ rails -v
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/exe/rails (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'

Comment: I have two guesses:
1) Try to run `bundle install` command from your project path to install missing rails;
2) Try to wrap commands in the `bundle exec` command - it will avoid conflicts (I see two ruby installations) e.g. `bundle exec rails s`

Comment: @user1201917 I have run both commands and have gotten the same output     $ bundle exec rails s
C:/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/specifications/default/exe/rails (LoadError)
        from C:vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'

Comment: @Darren If Ruby is installed properly you shouldn't be getting an error when typing `gem --version`? If you get an error,  try installing Ruby once again from https://rubyinstaller.org/. Otherwise, try installing rails (i.e. `C:\> gem install rails`).

Comment: @Darren, I'm sorry, use `gem env`. That gives us system information about how Ruby is installed.